SSRS vs PowerBI
I am working on a project that is implementing PowerBI. I come from a SSRS background but I have a team that knows PowerBI. My role in this project is to give report specs to the PowerBI guys and they can build the reports. But I am beginning to run into some challenges with PowerBI that I took for granted in SSRS and I want to run it by the forum to understand if these are real limitations or if maybe my PowerBI team needs to research more.
Here is what I need to do (and this is nothing crazy... all very typical components of report building, regardless of the reporting tool, I would think)
I want to give the PowerBI guys a stored procedure that returns a dataset to be used for the report. This stored proc can take a bunch of parameters.
I would like the PowerBI guys to populate drop down lists for each of the required parameters in whatever way I specify for them. I might give them a select statement, or simply a hard coded list. But bottom line, we populate drop down lists for each parameter required to run the stored proc.
Users will choose the parameter values from these drop down lists and those values will then get passed into the stored proc that will return the data for the report.
You can do this in SSRS and but for some reason, the PowerBI team is having a hard time implementing this. What they seem to want to do is define one dataset that comes from the underlying report data and use the native filter options to navigate the retrieved data. I suppose I can work within this limitation, but it seems an unreasonable limitation.
It almost feels like PowerBI isn't the right tool for the type of report I am trying to do.

I was also from SSRS and started using PBI last year. The one dataset is how I would do it and then use filters on the page. Not sure why you consider it a limitation - just a different way. And prob more efficient with just one data pull.

Having used SSRS previously and now using Power BI. I can see the reason for confusion.
Power BI was designed from the ground up to use a STAR schema as the data source. This means you have a central fact table that is filtered by linked dimension tables. That is the pattern that most data warehouses will use.  If a Star schema is designed well. In conjunction with the veripaq engine then it can wgive very fast results.
The solution that is described might not work easily with Power BI. Also means that not using a number of other advanced features. Such as the vertipac engine, the DAX language and all that offers.
Whilst the approach that is suggested to use a stored proc with parameters is one solution. it will come with certain downsides such as those noted above.
Thinking of Power BI as "just" a report tool, can mean that there are advantages. Also other benefits that cannot take advantage of. To make use of these other advantages requires a change of mindset. This is not easy, that said I do consider it worth the time.
Is Power BI the right tool, that I cannot comment on without more information. It is now possible to host Paginated reports (SSRS) in the Power BI service. So that is also an option.
